# Taking a Projects Development to the Next Level

Tags: asp.net, database, algorithm, visual-studio, ms-access

I have been looking for some advice for a while on how to handle a project I am working on, but to no avail. I am pretty much on my fourth iteration of improving an "application" I am working on; the first two times were in Excel, the third Time in Access, and now in Visual Studio. The field is manufacturing.

The basic idea is I am taking read-only data from a massive Sybase server, filtering it and creating much smaller tables in Access daily (using delete and append Queries) and then doing a bunch of stuff. More specifically, I use a series of queries to either combine data from multiple tables or group data in specific ways (aggregate functions), and then I place this data into a table (so I can sort and manipulate data using DAO.recordset and run multiple custom algorithms). This process is then repeated multiple times throughout the database until a set of relevant tables are created.

Many times I will create a field in a query with a value such as 1.1 so that when I append it to a table I can store information in the field from the algorithms. So as the process continues the number of fields for the tables change.

The overall application consists of 4 "back-end" databases linked together on a shared drive, with various output (either front-end access applications or Excel).

So my question is is this how many data driven applications that solve problems essentially work? Each backend database is updated with fresh data daily and updating each takes around 10 seconds (for three) and 2 minutes(for 1).

Project Objectives. I want/am moving to SQL Server soon. Front End will be a Web Application (I know basic web-development and like the administration flexibility) and visual-studio will be IDE with c#/.NET.

Should these algorithms be run "inside the database," or using a series of C# functions on each server request. I know you're not supposed to store data in a database unless it is an actual data point, and in Access I have many columns that just hold calculations from algorithms in vba.

The truth is, I have seen multiple professional Access applications, and have never seen one that has the complexity or does even close to what mine does (for better or worse). But I know some professional software applications are 1000 times better then mine.

So Please Please Please give me a suggestion of some sort. I have been completely on my own and need some guidance on how to approach this project the right way.

Comment: First step design database. Read some tutorials then have a look at http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/

Comment: The main reason I store it in Access is, for instance, I cut one data table down from 2 million rows down to 15,000. Access has a hard enough time running algorithms in the 15,000 row table, it would probably just crash if I didn't cut the table up. Plus I am only interested in data for my factory, not every factory. At least for this version... You did help me clearly figure out the major strange thing I am doing- using an access database as a data manipulation/algorithm/statistics tool rather than a data storage tool.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to sql server or any other full client server DBMS for that matter, the trick (generally) is to do as much on the server as possible.

Depends on how you've written the code really. In general the optimisations for a desktop are the inverse of those for a server.

For instance if you a Find Customer facility.

In a desktop you'd get the entire table and then use say Locate to find the record by name, post/zip code etc. Because effectively your application is both server and client.

In a Client Server set up, you pass customer Name etc to the DBMS, and let it find the customer(s) that matched and pass only those back.

So in your situation forgetting the web application bit, you've got to look at what your application does and say can I write this in sql.

So

If you had

```
// get orders 
foreach(Order order in clientOrders)
{
   if (Order.Discount > 0)
   {
      Order.Value = Order.ItemCount * Order.ItemPrice * Order.Discount;
   }
}
// save orders
```

you'd replace that with a query that did

```
Update Orders Set Value = ItemCount * ItemPrice * Discount 
Where ClientID = @ClientID and Discount > 0
```

Let the server do the work on the server instead of pulling and pushing loads of data into and out of an application.

If I was you though, I'd either do the sql server piece, or I'd do the web server piece, not both at the same time. In terms of client server there's a lot of overlap. Neither one precludes the other, but a lot of times you'll be able to use either to solve the same problem in slightly different ways.

Comment: Something like Select * From Table Order By SomeColumn Desc Limit 1 will get you the last row in that order. It's not row order doesn't matter, it's that you shouldn't assume it...

Answer (score 1):

As more details emerge, it appears one piece of your application involves storing 15K rows in your Access db file(s) so that you may later perform computations on those data.

However, it's not clear why you feel those data must be stored in Access to perform the computations.

Ideally, we would create a query to ask the server to perform those calculations.  If that's not possible with your server's capabilities, or so computationally intensive as to place an unacceptable processing load on the server, you still should not need to download all the raw data to Access in order to use it for your computations.  Instead, you could open a recordset populated by a query on the server, move through the recordset rows to perform your computation and store only the results in your Access table (via a second recordset).

```
Public Sub next_level_outline()
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rsLocal As DAO.Recordset
    Dim rsServer As DAO.Recordset
    Dim varLastValue As Variant

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rsLocal = db.OpenRecordset("AccessTable", dbOpenTable, dbAppendOnly)
    Set rsServer = db.OpenRecordset("ServerQuery", dbOpenSnapshot)
    Do While Not rsServer.EOF
        rsLocal.AddNew
        rsLocal!computed_field = YourAlgorithm(varLastValue)
        rsLocal.Update
        varLastValue = rsServer!indicator_field.value
        rsServer.MoveNext
    Loop
    rsLocal.Close
    Set rsLocal = Nothing
    rsServer.Close
    Set rsServer = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```

That is only a crude outline.  Much depends on the nature of `YourAlgorithm()`.  From a comment, I gathered it has something to do with a previous row ... so I included `varLastValue` as a placeholder.

Part of your approach was to filter 2 million source rows to the 15K rows which apply to your selected factory.  Do that with a `WHERE` clause in `ServerQuery`:

```
WHERE factory_id = 'foo'
```

If the row ordering is important for `YourAlgorithm()`, include an `ORDER BY` clause in `ServerQuery`.

The driver for this suggestion is to avoid redundantly storing data in Access.  And, if you can't eliminate the redundancy completely, at least limit the extent of it.

You may then find you can consolidate the Access storage into a single db file rather than four.  The single db file could simplify other aspects of your application and should also offer improved performance.

I think you should make certain you've thoroughly addressed this issue before you move on to the next stage of your application's evolution.  I don't believe this challenge will become any easier in ASP.Net.

Comment: Your question seems to be a moving target.  I suggested that VBA procedure because I guessed it might roughly resemble what you already had for  your algorithm in Access.  There is likely a better way if you will be doing this in SQL Server.  Perhaps you could ask about that in a new question.

Answer (score 1):

The application you describe appears to be an example of "[ETL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load)" - extract, transform, load.

It was one of the first projects I ever worked on as a professional programmer - and it's distinctly non-trivial. There are a bunch of tools you can use to help with this process (including one from Microsoft), but they are aimed mostly at populating a data warehouse - it's not clear that's what you're building, so that may not be hugely useful. Nevertheless, read through the Wikipedia article, and perhaps look at some of the ETL tools to get some ideas.

If you go your own way, I'd suggest writing a windows service to automatically run your ETL process. I assume you run the import on some kind of trigger - nightly, hourly, when the manufacturing system sends you a message or whatever; write your windows service to poll for this trigger.

I'd then execute whatever database commands from the service you need to move the data around, run your algorithms etc; pay attention to error handling and logging (services don't have a user interface, so you have to write errors to the system log and make sure someone is paying attention). Consider wrapping your database code in stored procedures - it makes them easier to invoke from the service.

It sounds like this is a fairly complex app; pay attention to code quality, consider unit tests (though it's hard to unit test database code). Buy "Code complete" by Steve McConnell and read it cover to cover if you're not a professional coder.